# Save html5 canvas DataURL to mySQL (PHP, Javascript, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html, html5-canvas

My issue: I have the ajax code to take form elements and simple strings to a mysql db, but I'm not able to save the dataURL to mysql due to the way I'm passing it.

I'm using

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I can alert(str) as the dataURL and it displays fine, but I'm not able to send it to the php page due to the characters within a dataURL. I know my code works because I can set str = "cheese" and it sets my database to cheese.

How can I get around this? I've looked into "Post" but I'm not sure if that will help me either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET is not the best place to be passing data that could potentially be very long. Browsers have limits on how long a query string can be, and it's different for every one.

That being said, since the dataurl contains 'bad' characters, you'd need to pass it through [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to make it valid for use in a URL.

However, consider switching to using POST - it has no client-side length limit as URLs do.

Comment: So using POST do you still pass it in a URL query string like "gethint.php?q="

I'm very new to ajax. Also is there a better way to getting a dataURL to a database? I do need to pull this in the future and I'm afraid the encodeURLComponent() will rune the dataURL if I try to pull it

Comment: No. You *can* use query parameters in urls for posts, but post data generally goes inside the request body. ajax isn't anything special. it just takes a regular http request that'd you "see" in the front-end of a browser (e.g. when submitting a form) and makes it happen in the background instead. once you strip off the hype/buzzwords, it's still just regular HTTP requests.

Comment: I dont know what to do then for this project.. My end goal was to take what was drawn on the canvas and save it to a database so the user could access, vew, and change it later on. It is a slide annotation application for tablets using html5. Can you think of a good way of going about this? Its also important that its not a save d image due to the slides are constantly changed by the professor, but i want the student annotations to stay the same

Comment: a canvas tag is more like MS Paintbrush. once something's drawn on a canvas, there's no vector information left over and you've just got a bitmap. Sounds like you'd want to deal with SVG images, which are vector-based from the get-go.

Comment: Well thank you very much for the help, i suppose you answered my question. Guess I'm stuck with notes only.